# A Custom Button in Android

Tags: android, button, android-custom-view

I am new to android.

I am trying to add a custom button to my app. When I insert a *.9.png image with edge marking, its displaying like this:

[image: with markings along edges]

If I remove edges and insert, its displaying like this:

[image: without markings along edges]

and it also giving error like this:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Crunching Cruncher button_focused.9.png failed, see logs
>
> Log:
> AAPT err(Facade for 1757000427):        No marked region found along edge.

I want to display like in the second image. The button looks like this:

```
<Button 
   android:id="@+id/btnButton1" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
   android:background="@drawable/button_background"
   android:text="@string/button_send" 
   android:onClick="designs"/>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Code block for the image.
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="designs"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple, I think you are not marking this image correctly and also I am not sure If you are using draw9patch Android tool or else, you don't need to mark the edges.

Please see [here](http://tekeye.biz/2012/android-9patch-files) for details that how to correctly mark the sides to maintain its shape while stretch.

Comment: Thanks Farhan. So useful answer. I just made a small mistake. After reading the article which you have shared, I knew what mistake I have done. 
Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

Use angry tool to generate button background http://angrytools.com/android/button/.

It allows you to style your view background by setting radius, stroke, background etc and gives you .xml file. Just copy paste it into your drawable folder and set it as background to your views.

Comment: I have already checked it. But, I want my own designed button to be my background.
Can you suggest anything else ?